# Convert date to string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

let date="20-05-2022";

const dates=new Date(date);

const out=dates.toString();

console.log(out);

The above snippet output is invalid date.

How to I convert this kind of date format to string.

How to I convert that??.

Comment: you write javascript in the title, then use the java tag, why? Also I bet there are thousands of questions or tutorials about this topic, have you done any research?

Comment: mistakenly i give that java tag.

Comment: i am a new bee to stackoverflow thats why this kind of mistakes i made.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) only supports the parsing of strings that meet [a simplified version of the ISO 8601 datetime format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format).

You have a number of options, including:

1. Rearrange the string to be 'YYYY-MM-DD' before passing it to the `Date` constructor, or
2. Parse the year, month and day number values and then pass these into the `Date` constructor as individual parameters like so: `new Date(year, monthIndex, day)`, or
3. Use a library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Be careful about timezones: date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, while date-time strings (e.g. "1970-01-01T12:00") are treated as local, or, if a timezone offset is supplied (e.g. `Z` or `+02:00`), according to that.

And when passing individual numbers for each datetime component to the `Date` constructor, values are treated as local.

A new, more featureful time API ([Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/)) is under development.